# More efficient way to use images on sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im making a school project in which i need to pre-load more than 100 images to sqlite database and then use them in listviews and imageviews.

What do you think its the most efficient way to use them??
Blob? Path?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @pskink can you give some examples of use of path??

Comment: example?  store an image on the file system and keep its path in the db,  thats all

Comment: @pskink i cant find easy to understand info about it, do you know any url? And the problem is im not sure what the path is

Answer (score 1):

On the system where this was [tested](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html), images smaller than 100 KB are more efficiently stored as a blob.

On your system, you have to measure.